# Spark: error: value split is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, split, rdd

The code snippet I was trying to execute:

```
val textfile = sc.textFile("small_file.txt")
            val arr = textfile.split(",")
            for (v <- arr) {
                println(v)
```

The packages that I included:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
```

The error that I got:

```
<console>:54: error: value split is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]
                val arr = textfile.split(",")
                               ^
```

Any lead would be appreciated!!

Comment: Please read some documentation ! Don't massacre spark. Such examples are available on the official documentation page. If you would researched a bit the subject you would have found the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It says clearly that split is not the method of RDD. Hence if you want to split the data inside the text file on the basis of ", " then you have to use the map function of RDD.

```
textfile.map(line=>line.split(","))
```

For more information you can see the example of word count here.

http://spark.apache.org/examples.html

Answer (score -5):

```
 val textfile = sc.textFile("small_file.txt")
```

variable textfile is RDD[String] and not string and that's why you are getting exception as split method is not member of RDD[String], so if you have to print content of textfile you can use

```
textfile.foreach(println) (shorter version)
```

or

```
textfile.foreact(x => println(x)) (longer version)
```

Thanks

Comment: This is not correct at any level neither it answer the OP's question.